# Wordpress site domain changed and jQuery breaks; nginx-based

Tags: nginx, php, wordpress, domain-name, jquery

trying to troubleshoot why jQuery isn't working after I change the domain in the Wordpress site URL. I'm getting these messages in the nginx debug log...

```
    2017/10/18 16:01:59 [info] 6657#6657: *495 epoll_wait() reported that client prematurely closed connection, so upstream connection is closed too while reading upstream, client: 221.234.103.135, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.8.2 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/";
    2017/10/18 16:02:03 [info] 6657#6657: *498 epoll_wait() reported that client prematurely closed connection, so upstream connection is closed too (32: Broken pipe) while reading upstream, client: 221.234.103.135, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/";
    2017/10/18 16:02:03 [info] 6657#6657: *506 client 221.234.103.135 closed keepalive connection
    2017/10/18 16:02:04 [info] 6657#6657: *504 epoll_wait() reported that client prematurely closed connection, so upstream connection is closed too (32: Broken pipe) while reading upstream, client: 221.234.103.135, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/";
    2017/10/18 16:02:04 [info] 6657#6657: *496 epoll_wait() reported that client prematurely closed connection, so upstream connection is closed too while reading upstream, client: 221.234.103.135, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.8.2 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/";
    2017/10/18 16:02:04 [info] 6657#6657: *507 client 221.234.103.135 closed keepalive connection
```

The only changes that were made to the configuration were the nginx server address and the Wordpress site URL. The site runs fine, but jQuery doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should check the database and do a search and replace

Comment: thanks for the reply, check the db for what?  what should i replace? There's a problem with enqueing the scripts. for some reason the js files aren't being served. the console shows errors.

Comment: Do a databasedump, and do a search and replace of your old url to your new one.